# Part of fullscreen missing in ETS2

Tags: steam, fullscreen

In Euro Truck Simulator 2 a part of the Fullscreen is missing:

[image]

Note that the bar at the top is still present and looks like exactly whats missing at the bottom (there is Text under the Icons)

In Minecraft it takes up the whole Screen which is basically the Point of Fullscreen.

Also in the Picture you can see that Fullscreen is ticked, unticking it changes nothing at all.(The Setting is changed but it looks the same)

As I said in Minecraft it works fine so I think its a problem with the game, but its fully supported on Linux (without Proton, wine etc) by the developers so I dont know what to do.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is an old issue and seems not fixed yet. Disabling others displays works for me. But yes, it inconvenient

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try *Properties* → *Compatibility* and change to *Steam Linux Runtime*. It worked for me.

Comment: well... game will run under Steam Proton instead the ETS2 linux native version. It could be undesired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the compatibility to the latest proton (not experimental). This can be done with going to the game in steam and then click the settings button for ets2 properties -> compatability -> check the checkbox and try which one works for you.

Comment: Game will run under Steam Proton instead the ETS2 linux native version. It could be undesired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the workaround below will work or not, but it worked for me.
**My Setup:**
OS: Debian 11
GPU: 3070ti
Steam runtime: deb package downloaded from VALVE site.
ETS2 version: 1.47

Displays:

1. 1920X1080 144Hz (main display)
2. 2560X1080 75Hz
3. 1440X900 75Hz

[image]

Workaround:

It seems the root of the problem for me was the highest refresh rate of the main display.
**Seeting (cfg file) the main monitor's refresh rate to a value less than 144hz worked. That is: 120Hz, 75Hz, 60Hz**
So fullscreen worked on main screen/display with no border crossing another display/monitor.
Also, here goes some relevant values from my `config.cfg`:

```
uset r_fullscreen "1"
uset r_mode_refresh "120"
uset r_mode_height "1080"
uset r_mode_width "1920"
# disable multi monitor
uset r_multimon_mode "0"
```